Why SSA cannot prove two triangles to be similar?
I have learned that $\text{SAS}$ can prove two triangles to be similar or congruent. The textbook also states that $\text{SSA}$ cannot be used to perform the similarity test, but does not give a reason.

Related (duplicate?): "Similarity by SSA (side-side-angle) in obtuse triangles"

Sides AB and AB' are equal length.
Sides AC and AC are equal length.
Angle at C = Angle at C.
But ABC and AB'C are not congruent (or even similar) because one has a right angle but the other does not.
So "SSA congruence/similarity" isn't a theorem because it's not true. (See, however, the post linked in the comments.)


I suppose that angle at C is different, also angle at A and B' are both obtuse, so they look similar

You're completely correct. I got so annoyed messing with powerpoint that I completely forgot to put B on the line through C and B'. Fixed now.  The "obtuseness" remark was just stupid, and I've fixed that, too.

...and I've now edited to give an even more compelling reason.
